# django rest framework filter_backends class called before permission_classes class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-framework-filters

I have a DRF view-set with a custom permission and filter. In DRF's official [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#permissions) it says:

> Permission checks are always run at the very start of the view, before any other code is allowed to proceed.

But I have noticed that my filter_backend class is called before permission_class. Here is my code:

```py
# my permission
from rest_framework import permissions


class CompanyAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'Detail of company not allowed.'

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("permission")
        return request.user in obj.users.all()
```

```py
# my filter
from rest_framework import filters


class IsCompanyOwnerFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        print("filter")
        return queryset.filter(users__in=[request.user])
```

```py
# my view
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from api import filters, permissions, serializers
from core import models


class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                     mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, permissions.CompanyAccessPermission)
    filter_backends = [filters.IsCompanyOwnerFilterBackend]
    queryset = models.Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CompanySerializer
```

So when I want to retrieve a Company object the output is as follows:

```py
> filter
> permission
```

I was expecting the opposite of that. I also looked at the source code of DRF `class GenericViewSet(ViewSetMixin, generics.GenericAPIView)`. It seems like the permission class (called in `views.APIView`) is called before the filter backend class (called in `generics.GenericAPIView`i which inherits `views.APIView`). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have noticed what's going on. Here is the execution of permission_class methods and filter_backend_methods:

1. permission_classes' `.has_permission(self, request, view)` method, which I **did not** override.
2. filter_backends' `.filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view)` method.
3. permission_classes' `.has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj)` method, which I **did** override.

As I was performing an object-level permission (overriding`has_object_permission` method), my custom filter was executed before, which makes more sense.